# ng xi18n per module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, angular6

Is there a way to extract the translation files **per angular module**? My app:

- app

  - module-1 --> Team 1 works in this module
  - module-2 --> Team 2 works in this module
  - module-3 --> Team 3 works in this module
  - messages.xlf
  - messages.fr.xlf
  - ...

There is a big potential for a lot of merge conflicts in our git flow in messages.xlf after each new generation (*ng xi18n*)

Is there a chance to extract the xlf file per module?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same logical problem with our app. 
There is a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11431#issue-175687310) on github. 
But still there is no solution or workaround.

Comment: You should not post this as an answer. This is just a comment, it should be in the Comments section